# MVC Extension Method HtmlHelper Method Signature Syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, extension-methods

I wrote the following code to format prices on a C# MVC 5 website. Looking at it again, I have no idea how it works.

What is the "this" keyword doing in a static function method signature? Why do I need to pass in the html argument at all, it's not used in the function? How does this even compile?

**this HtmlHelper html** is the part I find confusing. How is it legal to use the "this" keyword in that way?

```
public static MvcHtmlString PrettyUSD(this HtmlHelper html, int amount)
        {
            if (amount == 0)
            {
                return MvcHtmlString.Create("N/A");
            }
            else
            {
                return MvcHtmlString.Create(string.Format("{0:C0}", amount));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an [*extension method*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx). Extension methods are just a syntactic sugar. It's the `this` keyword that actually marks this method as being an extension method.

From the docs:

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type. Extension methods are a special kind of static method, but they are called as if they were instance methods on the extended type. For client code written in C# and Visual Basic, there is no apparent difference between calling an extension method and the methods that are actually defined in a type.

You can call your method like this:

```
html.PrettyUSD(42);
```

This is strictly equivalent to this:

```
YourClassName.PrettyUSD(html, 42);
```

It's the same mechanism that lets you write, for instance:

```
new[] { 1, 4, 10, 42 }.Average();
```

The `Array` type doesn't have an `Average` method, but the `System.Linq.Enumerable` class has one defined like this (at least it's one of its overloads):

```
public static double Average(this IEnumerable<int> source)
```

As you can see, this lets you define a method just like if it were declared on the `IEnumerable<int>` interface.

Your function doesn't use the `HtmlHelper` class, but it's used so that it can be used in the conventional ASP.NET MVC Razor way:

```xml
The price is <strong>@Html.PrettyUSD(42)</strong>
```

Comment: That's very javascripty! So the use of the "this" keyword in the method signature is idiomatic? It just looks odd to have 3 tokens being used in one argument.

Comment: Yes, it's C# syntax. And believe me, it reads much better when you chain these methods: `something.Where(...).Distinct()` is easier to read than `Enumerable.Distinct(Enumerable.Where(something, ...))`. Imagine you have a longer chain.

Comment: I always wondering how those "fluent" style APIs actually compiled. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To answer "Why do I need to pass in the html argument at all, it's not used in the function?"...

In your particular case you don't use it, but it can be very useful because it gives you access to the `ViewBag`, `ViewData`, and a whole lot of other properties.  For example, here is an extension method that replaces line breaks with `<br />` for formatting text, and it takes a lambda expression instead of a straight value.

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayWithBreaksFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, html.ViewData);
    var model = html.Encode(metadata.Model).Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br />");

    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(model))
        return MvcHtmlString.Empty;

    return MvcHtmlString.Create(model);
}
```

Note how it's evaluating the `expression` against `html.ViewData` to get the model property to format.  Usage would be something like:

`Html.DisplayWithBreaksFor(model => model.Description)`